# url connection error with try and catch

Tags: java, android, web-applications, webview, try-catch

I try to create with try and catch blocks in android a way to handle with no internet connection or if the webserver is down. In eclipse `IOException` is red underlined. If the loading of `http://192.168.0.23/loc/index.php` fails, `"file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html"` should become loaded. I know only try and catch from php and have looked actually any tutorials but cant find my mistake.

**It shows the following message:**

> Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

**my code:**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_localy);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());     
    // Load google.com
    try {
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.23/loc/index.php");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Means that the code that you've put on your `try` doesn't fire any `IOException` try to put `Exception e` as follows :

```
 try {
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.23/loc/index.php");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(e.getMessage()); //Get the Exception thrown.
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

}
```

And you'll know what Exception you are getting.

Comment: Why did you unmarked my answer as a correct, didn't work?

Comment: Isn't my answer working for you? Shall I update my answer?

Answer (score 1):

[loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't throw an `IOException` :

> **public void loadUrl (String url)**
>
> Loads the given URL. 
> **Parameters**
>  **url** the URL of the resource to load

Which is why you shouldn't try to catch `IOException` (you can only catch exceptions that may be thrown by the code of the try block).

Just replace the entire try-catch block with a single statement :

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.23/loc/index.php");
```

As for how to detect errors in the loading of the URL, the link above contains this code sample :

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });
 webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
```

So, to adjust it to your code :

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");
   }
 });
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.23/loc/index.php");
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: That work if no internet connection is available but in the case of available internet the webview show only index.php. If index.php have a redireting the errorpage become shown.